# Filtering arrays for neighbors

Tags: java, arrays, nearest-neighbor

Is there an easy way to filter an array of elements quickly to only output the neighbors?

Say I have an array of elements. Now I want to find the neighbors of a specific element.

The code I made works but looks quite ugly and I'd like to find an easier-to-read solution.

My code:

```
int[] myArray = {6, 8, 9, 12, 30};
// index of element where I want to find the neighbors of
int index = 1;

if(index == 0){
  //first element so only add the right neighbor
  System.out.println(myArray[1]);
} else if(index == myArray.length -1){
  //last element so only add left neighbor
  System.out.println(myArray[index-1]);
} else{
  //middle element so add both neighbors
  System.out.println(myArray[index-1]);
  System.out.println(myArray[index+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good and short solution:

```
if(index > 0) System.out.println(myArray[index-1])
if(index < array.length-1) System.out.println(myArray[index+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using Java 8 you can use this by quite simple lambda solution:

```
final int[] numbs = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };
int index = 2;
IntStream.rangeClosed(index - 1, index + 1)
        .filter(idx -> idx != index && idx >= 0 && idx < numbs.length)
        .forEach(idx -> System.out.println(numbs[idx]));
```

But please, create a method that receives your array and index in order to reuse the code.

Comment: I do not think that this is a good idea, because the streams usually perform for a long time. Also, lambdas are usually more difficult to understand than simple if-else.

Comment: no need to stream the entire range of the array. you can stream just the neighbors `IntStream.rangeClosed(index-1, index+1)` and filter `idx != index && idx >= 0 && idx < numbs.length`

Comment: And yes, lambdas are hard to understand for people who doesn't study them. So don't use if you don't know how to use them @AntonSorokin and do never use the new Java features too.

Comment: @RhuanKarlus My message doesn`t mean that I don`t know lambda or I propose not to learn/use new language features. I meant that it is not necessary to use a complicated version when there is a simpler construction.